# Parsing JSON string without quotes

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've got code like below (it just edit JSON and put new stuff in place pointed by JSONPath):

```
JToken jp = JToken.Parse(json);
IEnumerable<JToken> nd = jp.SelectTokens(path);

JToken newj = JToken.Parse(newval);

foreach (JToken vl in nd)
    ((JToken)value).Replace(newj);
```

**json**, **path**, **newval** are strings. I've got no problem when i'm trying to add new int, float, date, bool, null etc... Problem is when i'm trying to add string. Format with quotes is correct ("newstring"), but I need to add string without quotes as well, but i've got an exception ("Unexpected end when reading JSON. Path ''[...]).

Is there any option to parse string without quotes?

Comment: How can we help unless you post the Json string? Besides - why do you expect to parse a *string* when the value is *not* a string, ie it isn't enclosed in quotes?

Comment: It could be any valid JSON. I'm getting value to edit form user, so if user forgot about quotes (if want to add string) i don't know if there is any way to add quotes in code.

Comment: JSON uses quotes to delimit strings. If the input doesn't have quotes, it's not valid JSON. You can't *guess* how to recover either - newlines are valid in a string, so the rest of the file can be considered a single string. Besides, why would a *user* enter the text directly? Shouldn't there be a *validation* step that prevented them from creating invalid JSON?

Comment: What is 'string without quotes' ? Quotes are only used in C# to work with string values, but when it comes to serialization, it serializes string without quotes. But json format requires quotes for key/value pair and serializer automatically adds them to match the formatting requirements.

Comment: @Fabjan valid string for JSON from C# point-of-view is "\"string\"". I want to parse string which looks like "string" (without escaping).

Comment: @JamesTheEvangelist escape symbols are only there because otherwise it's not possible to use double quotes inside of C# app. So this string  - "\"text\"" inside c# app being serialized will become "text" which is exactly how json value should be formatted  -  "propname" : "value"

Answer (score 1):

A string in JSON is [defined](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) as

> A string is a sequence of Unicode code points wrapped with quotation marks (U+0022).

If your input contains non-numeric characters that aren't surrounded by quotes, you have an invalid JSON string.

BTW, JSON doesn't define dates either. The ISO 8601 format is used by convention.

Comment: As you wrote in comment - now i'm validate textbox with input and don't let users to wrote values without quotes.

Comment: Why don't you wrap Strings in `\"` yourself?

Comment: @Toxantron because it's impossible to guess in code. JSON strings can have newlines which means that anything up to the end of file can be a valid string. You can't even assume that a string doesn't cross lines, as the text is entered by end users.